SQL Query to search and replace fails with invalid object
I am trying to find all tables that have a certain column and then search that column for a given value and replace it.
My Query looks like this:
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Iterate through each table
DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT t.name
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.name = 'CHAMBERID'

OPEN table_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @Sql = N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) +
               N' SET CHAMBERID = REPLACE(CHAMBERID, ''1'', ''9'')'
    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql

    FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @TableName
END

CLOSE table_cursor
DEALLOCATE table_cursor

When I run the query, I get the following error message
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'CI_AAA_HARDWARE'.

When I select that table and look at the data, the column exists and the search string exists. I do not understand why it fails.
Does anybody have an idea where I am going wrong?
Thank you all :)
Alex

Which dbms are you using? The above code is product specific.

You are not taking into account the schema. You need to join sys.schemas for that.
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(520);
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @crsr CURSOR;

-- Iterate through each table
SET @crsr = CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY FOR
SELECT CONCAT(QUOTENAME(s.name), '.', QUOTENAME(t.name))
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.name = 'CHAMBERID';

OPEN @crsr;

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM @crsr INTO @TableName;
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK;

    SET @Sql = N'
UPDATE ' + @TableName + N'
SET CHAMBERID = REPLACE(CHAMBERID, ''1'', ''9'')
WHERE CHAMBERID LIKE ''%1%'';'
    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql;
END;
-- don't need to close cursors in variables


Thank you @Charlieface :)
I was considering the schemas but did not think I needed it because I did not need it when I perform searches and have the results shown. But I guess there I did not actually perform a task on the tables.
